# how to replace bindwithevent in mootools 1.3

Tags: javascript, mootools

I wonder how to replace the bindWithEvent function in Mootools 1.3, the example in the documentation is very basic:

```
Element.addEvent('click', function(e){
myFunction.bind(bind, [e]);});
```

But, what about if I need to pass a param to the event handler? This is the way in Mootools 1.2:

```
Element.addEvent('click', function(e, param) { e.stop(); alert(param) }.bindWithEvent(this,['text']);
```

Any idea on how to replace this in Mootools 1.3.

Update: I found a very ugly solution, but a least it works while I find a built-in solution:

```
Element.addEvent('click', function(e){ e.stop(); this.bind.myFunc(this.param);}.bind({bind:this, param: 'text'}));
```

Comment: please update with fix and turn into a community wiki for others to see as this question is being asked a lot lately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
el.addEvent('click', function(event){
    myFunction(event, param1, param2); // can use .pass and bind this again
}.bind(this));
```

it's hard to explain why it got deprecated though.

example in a class context:

```
var foo = new Class({
    initialize: function(el) {
        document.id(el).addEvent('click', function(event){
            this.foo(event, "hello");
        }.bind(this));
    },
    foo: function(event, what) {
        console.log(event, this); // this is the class instance
        alert(what);
    }
});

new foo("foo");
```

Comment: I like that! But isn't the "this" context lost inside `myFunction`?

Comment: not really. http://www.jsfiddle.net/dimitar/Ty5DJ/ - read my revised example. you can always use .pass when you call the function to change the scope...

Comment: What about if I need to pass a "what" param which is a var outside of the event handler document.id(el).addEvent('click', function(event){ ... }.bind(this));

Comment: in the second example i pass on 'hello' - this can actually be a var from any scope you can reference or a provate var to the class, eg, `this.name = 'foo'` ... `this.foo(event, this.name);` etc etc. i don't see what the hold up is - the only real downside to bindWithEvent being gone is that it all looks less tidy. :(

Comment: Please check http://www.jsfiddle.net/2tcRU/, this is my case. As you can see no matter which element you click, the alert is always "hello4"

Comment: totally unrelated to binding. this is a case of your event callback having a reference to `i` - which will be a static value set to the last iteration and not copied on event assignment as the 'then' value in the loop. http://www.jsfiddle.net/2tcRU/3/ also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4054915/echoing-the-then-state-of-variable-in-a-mootools-event-even-after-var-has-chang (question before yours in #mootools, oddly enough).

Comment: You are right! It was working for me using bindWithEvent. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the upgrade from 1.2 to 1.3 page: http://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/wiki/Update-from-1.2-to-1.3

This is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/MBx2D/2/

Comment: I did it before and it didn't help me

Comment: It isn't my case. I need to pass "this" as the scope for the event handler. Please check my solution.